# Can I find the Apple ID of an ios app through SDK?

Tags: ios

Can I find the Apple ID of an ios app through SDK? I have to write an aplication in which i will be in need of finding Apple Id and the username  for that Apple ID. Is somebody knows how to get that? Please help..

Comment: The apple ID of an app is a constant numeric value. It is shown in iTunes Connect and is also part of the App Store URL for the app.

Answer (score 0):

No. Apple ID is an user's privacy information, you can't get it from SDK.